# Array of JSON .count always returns 0 in Swift 4

Tags: arrays, json, swift, swifty-json

I got some issues with JSON in swift. When I get JSON data from userDefault storage (Array of JSON as String format) then parse it into JSON object and count number of object in array, but the result always return O (Zero).

My swift code:

```
 let carts = userStorage.object(forKey: userDefaultKeys.carts)
 print("logging carts....")
 print(JSON(carts  as! String).count)
 print(JSON(carts as! String))
```

And it logged into result window

```
logging carts....
0
[
 {
  "Lat" : 32,
  "Time" : null,
  "Items" : [
    {
     "StorePhone" : "018753678474",
     "Ingredient" : "",
     "FK_Category" : 2,
     "Enabled" : 1,
     "UpdatedAt" : null,
     "IsActive" : 1,
     "quantity" : 1,
    }
   ],
   "DeliveryFee" : null,
   "Photos" : "https:\/\/networkposting.com\/wpcontent\/uploads\/2018\/02\/maxresdefaul-137.jpg"
 }
]
```

Comment: which type of carts variabled

Comment: Give me full response

Comment: I defined it as an any-type variable

Comment: specify Array type

Comment: let carts:NSArray = userStorage.object(forKey: userDefaultKeys.carts) as! NSArray

Comment: Don't use NS classes in Swift unless you really have to. Most types have been bridged to Swift.

Comment: Yes, thanks @VishalVaghasiya and Scriptable ! Thankyou

Comment: @HoangHai Welcome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the [Usage Documentation on the GitHub page](https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON):

> **Initialization**

```
let json = JSON(data: dataFromNetworking)
```

or

```
let json = JSON(jsonObject)
```

or

```
if let dataFromString = jsonString.data(using: .utf8, allowLossyConversion: false) {
    let json = JSON(data: dataFromString)
}
```

So you can't init a SwiftyJSON object directly via String like you are.

If you have a JSON String... Use the bottom example above to convert it to data first.

Comment: Thanks alot. I converted String to Data first, then parsed data into object. It works well